# how to reslove modsec_audit.log errors

Tags: apache2, mod-security2

I did the following steps

1. `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-security2`
2. `sudo mv /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf-recommended /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf`
3. I edited the following lines as

   ```
   SecRuleEngine On
   SecAuditEngine On
   ```
4. I did `sudo service apache2 reload` and 
   when I am typing this `tail -f /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log` and I am getting error like this

   ```
   Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 271]
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42830351

Comment: i am not sending any large request bodies